# ZF2 toRoute with https

Tags: php, zend-framework2

We're using Zend Framework 2 and use `toRoute` within our controllers to redirect to various locations, for example `$this->redirect()->toRoute('home');`.

Is there anyway to have this redirect to https instead of http using this method or an alternative method?

Thank you!

Comment: If you look at the `Redirect` controller plugin's [toRoute](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/Redirect.php#L36-L52) method, you can see that it takes an `$options` array and calls the `Url` controller plugin's [fromRoute](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/Url.php#L33) method to build the URL. I would suspect that you can pass an option to it to do it (probably the same as for the `url` view helper). I don't have time to investigate it right now, so I didn't do so much digging. Maybe it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `https` in your route you need to use the `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Scheme` router. Specifying the configuration for such route is not very different from the other routes. You need to specify the route type as `Scheme` and add an option `'scheme' => 'https'` in your router configuration in module.config.php.

Here is an example:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'routename' => array(
                'type' => 'Scheme', // <- This is important
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/url',
                    'scheme' => 'https', // <- and this.
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'MdlNamespace\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'someAction',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // the rest of the routes
        ),
    ),
    // the rest of the module config
);
```

If you have the route `routename` configured like above, this: `$this->redirect()->toRoute('routename');` will work.

See [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-scheme) for reference to the ZF2's manual.

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan

Comment: The problem I have with the scheme route is that it's basically a literal route and seems terribly inconvenient. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-scheme The following post seems to provide a more flexible solution without having to suffer the limitations of Scheme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141140/zf2-and-force-https-for-specific-routes.