# zf2 https route not work

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I've a zf2 rest web service and my route is like this

```
'geo-province' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
       'route' => '/geo-province[/:id]',
       'defaults' => array(
          '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Geo\Controller',
          'controller' => 'GeoProvince',
       ),
    ),
 ),
```

if i use http all works fine but not if i use https.
i read that i need to use Schema type route but not work and in addition to it's a literal route but i need segment type route

this is new route

```
    'geo-province' => array(
    'type' => 'Schema',
    'options' => array(
       'route' => '/geo-province',
       'scheme' => 'https',
       'defaults' => array(
          '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Geo\Controller',
          'controller' => 'GeoProvince',
          'action'=>'index
       ),
    ),
 ),
```

how can i solve?

Comment: Have you read this post yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141140/zf2-and-force-https-for-specific-routes

Comment: Like Alex says above, you need to set child routes further to have a route match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http` and `https` requests are processed within the framework equal. 
i doesn't matter if you request a page over `http://example.com/foo/bar` or `https://example.com/foo/bar` if a route is configured like

```
'myroute' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
       'route' => '/foo[/bar]',
       'defaults' => array(
          'controller' => 'Some\Controller',
          'action' => 'someaction',
       ),
    ),
 ),
```

the `Http Scheme` comes in handy when you want to seperate actions between `http` and `https`. if your page is not displayed on `https` requests it is more likely that your web service is not properly configurated for ssl and the request are not directed to the `/public/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks. the problem was the security.conf apache. in practice .htaccess not being read and therefore nothing worked. Your suggestion put me on the right track.