# Zend framework 2 https link not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

**Site links**:

1. http://test.scampaigns.com/Frontend/index
2. https://test.scampaigns.com/Frontend/index

**Problem**:

Number 1 is working, number 2 is giving 404 error.

The problem is with HTTP the site is working fine. but with HTTPS only the default controller is working but other controllers are not working with the https:

Below is my module.config.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/', //edited by koushik
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),


                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[:controller[/:action]][/:id][/:pId][/:devId]', //edited by koushik
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),


            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Developer' => 'Application\Controller\DeveloperController', // edited by Poulami
            'Application\Controller\Template' => 'Application\Controller\TemplateController', // edited by Poulami
            'Application\Controller\Admin' => 'Application\Controller\AdminController',  
            'Application\Controller\Frontend' => 'Application\Controller\FrontendController',
            'Application\Controller\Ajaxcall' => 'Application\Controller\AjaxcallController'
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions' => true,
        'doctype' => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
        'exception_template' => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
     'translator' => array(
   'locale' => 'en_US',
      'translation_file_patterns' => array(
         array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
         ),
      ),
   ),// Added by Baishakhi
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Is there any one who can help me and give me solution?

Comment: thanks @jww for your help. but can you give me some kind of solution?

Comment: Did you try to use a Scheme route? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797599/zf2-toroute-with-https

Comment: yes I all ready tried with this schema route setup. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

zend doesn't matter what url scheme is used when trying to find a `RouteMatch` with your router configuration.

i think your problem is located in your apache configuration that your `https` vhost don't allow `.htaccess` files in your public folder.

when all urls fail and the `index.php` is working - this indicates a rewrite problem. check your apache configuration and that your `public` folder can override `htaccess` files with the option

`AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `https` in your route you need to use the `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Scheme` router. All you need is to add an option in your route configuration: `'scheme' => 'https'`.

You can follow this simple example :

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'name_route' => array(
            'type' => 'Scheme', //<-----add the type Schema here.
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/url',
                'scheme' => 'https', //<-----specify this here.
                'defaults' => array(
                    //set the default options here.
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // ....
    ),
),
```

You can also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141140/zf2-and-force-https-for-specific-routes).